# building sql reports

Tags: sql, infomaker

I’m looking for a report that shows me the bookings summary by location,  the data I’m wanting to see is sale amount, Sales order (gm) and Profit %.
In a format similar to this

```
Sales Orders - Source Loc ID    Sales Orders - Sales Location   Sale Amt    Sales Orders - Gross Margin$    Sales Orders - Gross Margin%    Profit%(p21)
10  Mobile  $1,892.00   $473.00     25.00%  25.00%
20  Louisiana   $9,834.90   $1,966.97   20.00%  0.00%
30  Florida $3,547.32   $1,324.01   37.30%  0.00%
40  Birmingham  $328.48     $31.65  9.60%   0.00%
50  Northeast   $20,336.52  $4,067.30   20.00%  0.00%
```

The sale amount will be a sum of all sales, and the same with gross margin for that location.  The percentage will be an average of all the profit percentages in that location.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [GROUP BY](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1600/doc/html/san1390612143404.html) and [Aggregate Function](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X69737.htm)

The below query should give you the desired result:

```
SELECT [Sales Orders - Source Loc ID],[Sales Orders - Sales Location],
       SUM([Sale Amt]) AS [Sale Amt],
       SUM([Sales Orders - Gross Margin$]) AS [Sales Orders - Gross Margin$],
       AVG([Sales Orders - Gross Margin%]) AS [Sales Orders - Gross Margin%],
       AVG([Profit%(p21)]) AS [Profit%(p21)]
FROM Table
GROUP BY [Sales Orders - Source Loc ID],[Sales Orders - Sales Location]
```